# How to Map Static Handlers in App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, handler, yaml

I just starting to learn how to develop for App Engine and I am trying to organize my file structure and I have my static files under this hierarchy:

> root/themes/default/assets/styles

for my css files and my js is within:

> root/themes/default/assets/scripts

I am having trouble getting AE to serve the files when I put them in these folders.  If I put the css and js files in:

> root/themes/default/assets

I have no issues of them being served to the browser if I use the following in my app.yaml:

```
- url: /themes/(.+)/assets/(.+)
  static_files: themes/\1/assets/\2
  upload: themes/(.+)/assets/(.+)
```

I have tried several ways by trying to [follow the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers) but I am just not getting it. My question is what would be the proper way of writing the handlers to get to theses files with my organizational structure?

Your help is appreciated. Thnx

Comment: Out of curiosity, why overcomplicate things and not simply use '/themes' route?

Answer (score 1):

It might be your regexes are too greedy - try something like

```
- url: /themes/(.+)/assets/(styles|scripts)/(.+)
  static_files: themes/\1/assets/\2/\3
  upload: themes/(.+)/assets/(styles|scripts)/(.+)
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are trying to catch some very particular `404`s I would use something like this:

```
- url: /themes
  static_dir: themes
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that all the methods I was trying would have worked (including the above answers - so I upped them).  The reason why they were not was because there was an issue where the folders were not being deployed by Git which was bad timing making me think it was me.  Once the folders were deployed everything worked as it should.

Thnx again for your help.